# How to increase the number of context lines shown in the Node.js debugger when using node inspect from the command line?

Tags: node.js

Sample script:

main.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

x = 0;
x = 1;
x = 2;
x = 3;
x = 4;
x = 5;
x = 6;
x = 7;
x = 8;
x = 9;
x = 10;
x = 11;
x = 12;
x = 13;
x = 14;
x = 15;
x = 16;
x = 17;
x = 18;
x = 19;
```

Debug it with:

```
node inspect main.js
```

and I see only 5 lines of context at each time:

```
Break on start in main.js:3
  1 #!/usr/bin/env node
  2 
> 3 x = 0;
  4 x = 1;
  5 x = 2;
debug> n
break in main.js:4
  2 
  3 x = 0;
> 4 x = 1;
  5 x = 2;
  6 x = 3;
debug>
```

I know I can explicitly list more lines with:

```
list(10)
```

but how to change the number of context lines shown by default on each stop to something larger than just 5?

Also asking at: https://github.com/nodejs/node-inspect/issues/102

Tested on Node.js v12.18.1.

Comment: Just out of curiosity  - shouldn't it be `node --inspect main.js`?

Comment: @eol I think `--inspect` is to open it in a GUI debugger like Chrome, `node inspect` is for debugging in CLI.

Comment: Ah you're right, that's something I did not know. I've always used Webstorm/Chrome debugger so far. Thanks for the hint.